# embedding large js files into one page

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, embed, external

i want to use tinymce editor but my final html file must not contain any links to any sources or css files.
i mean there must not be any references to external resources, it should be embedded in one html
(all js files and css files)

performance is not important and the target browser is ie11 only.

i do not want any

```
<script src=".."> or
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="..">
```

i want that

```
<script>
function tinymce..
</script>
```

same as style info also should be in this html without any reference to outside.

due to the limits of native browsers on java applictions (djbrowser), i can deploy one one file, i do not go
deeply into technical details of ie11 with dj.

is that possible? or any method? because when i copy paste tiny_mce.js directly into the html it fails. The reason may be dynamically created scripts which are made by document.write.

my test cases:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- DO NOT CHANGE TITE -->
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/ui.css">       
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css">    

    <style>
        .mce-widget.mce-tooltip { display : none !important; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/plugins/table/editor_plugin.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/plugins/contextmenu/editor_plugin.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/plugins/paste/editor_plugin.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/langs/en.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

    function init() {
        // Check that tinymce exists
        if (typeof tinyMCE === 'undefined') {
                alert("tinymce.js is missing");
                return;
        }




        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "lists,style,linespace",

            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,listbox",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,outdent,indent,|,forecolor,backcolor",

            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : "true" 


        });
    }

            // Sets content
    function JH_setData(html) {
        try { 
            var oEditor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
            oEditor.setContent(html);  
            //Check whether decoding needed
            //oEditor.setContent(decodeURIComponent(html));  
        } catch(e) { 
            //alert('exception occured' + e.description + ' ' + e.message);  
            return 'FAIL';
        }
        return 'OK';
    }

    // Gets the content
    function JH_getData() {
        var oEditor = tinyMCE.activeEditor; 
        var val = oEditor.getContent();  
        return val;
     }  

    function setContent() {
        JH_setData('test content');
    }

    function getContent() {
        var content = JH_getData();
        alert('content:' + content);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
    <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 100%;height:100%"></textarea>


<input type=button class="button_fu_class" style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:600px;width:80px;height:23px" value="SetContent" onClick="javascript:setContent();">
<input type=button class="button_fu_class" style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:700px;width:80px;height:23px" value="GetContent" onClick="javascript:getContent();">
</body>
</html>
```

works, but if i copy pase the tiny_mce.sc into a script block whole page fails.

if i replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //content of tiny_mce.js 
 (function(d){var a=/^\s*|\s*$.....
</script>
```

it fails

Comment: Please give more detail.

Comment: ok, i need embed tinymce into djbrowser (http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html), until ie11 it worked without problems. after ie11 released, embedded tinycme is not working anymore becasue of security limits of ie11. to solve the problem, i create an html file which contains tinymce. and i load this into the djbrowser with loadurl from the disk. the html file contains references to tinymce.js and tinymce.css files.

Comment: suppose my editor is editor.html, editor.html contains a simple html and references to tinymce. in djbrowser i use djbrowser.load('c:\editor.html') it works but causes portability problems. when I set the content of editor.html into the djbrowser as content with djbrowser.setContent('<html><scr=..tinymce.js') it fails because of references. 
i want to embed all external references of js and css into one html string and set that as content.

Comment: Ok, <script type="text/javascript"></script> put all the JavaScript there, and for CSS, <style type="text/css"></style> simple? :)

Comment: nope. it fails. i tried that but i think it fails because of document.write(js..)

Comment: I don't think if anyone can help you, it's been 23 mins, you would've received some answers by now.. ;L

Comment: interestingly, it creates the tinyMCE  instance, when failed, (does not show the tinymce missing message) but the editor fails.